# setting returned ajax to variable to done() gives me an object

Tags: javascript, jquery

How come

```
ajaxFunction().done(function(p){
 console.log(p);
});
```

returns data as HTML as specified in `dataType` in the ajaxFunction, but

```
var data = ajaxFunction().done(function(p){
    console.log(data) 
    //returns what appears to be the entire deferred object
    //to see the returned HTML string, I have to do console.log(data.responseText);
});
```

What would be the practical application of having that object once I have it stored in data? Can I do something further with it? Or is it not intended to be used like this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your variable `data` is the *promise* returned by `ajaxFunction()`.

Having a reference to it allows you to add more `.done` callbacks, and also `.fail` callbacks, the latter being handy if your `ajaxFunction()` has no built-in error handling.

Within your callback functions it would be, umm, *unusual* to access that variable directly - it's `p` you're supposed to be using.

Comment: but I could do something like `var data = ajaxFunction(); data.done(function(p){alert(p);}).fail(function(){//});` ?

Comment: @thomas yes, that's exactly what you're supposed to do.